# No monospace fonts on qtwebengine browsers, chromium

Tags: fonts

I'm running archlinux with ttf-google-fonts-git package installed, so I have a lot of monospaced fonts like Noto Mono, Hack, Insonsolata, Consolas, etc. But, when I open any qtwebengine based browser(qutebrowser, falkon, zeal to read docs) or chromium, code blocks doesn't render correctly. Take a look at the screenshot from github:

[image: incorrect monospace rendering]

But at some pages it looks good, include stackowerflow:

[image: correct rendering]

I tried to follow instructions and advices from [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5r5ep8/make_your_arch_fonts_beautiful_easily/), also other sources that I googled but without success.

fc-match output is:

```
~ > fc-match monospace
NotoMono-Regular.ttf: "Noto Mono" "Regular"
```

Firefox renders all good, but I want to solve this issue anyway. Thanks

Comment: Use the Inspect tool in the Chromium browser to determine what font was originally requested. Also, check the `chrome://settings/fonts` page to be sure that the Fixed-width font is actually a monospace one.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have inspected elements and have found that on github.com the first font family in list is SFMono-Regular, then comes Consolas(which I have installed) and, finally, monospace(which is set to Noto Mono in settings). So, I have ended up installing Apple fonts SFMono(with a little trick - edited font name in FontForge to SFMono-Regular), Menlo, Monaco. Now rendering is fine, but anyway it feels not so right, I mean installing new fonts when browser should use existing system font instead of non-existing. 
Thanks.

Comment: You can create aliases in fontconfig (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration#Replace_or_set_default_fonts), no need to copy the font files. What does `fc-match "SFMono-Regular"` say in your original configuration?

Comment: It says: SFMono-Regular.otf: "SF Mono" "Regular".
Thanks for info about aliases. Missed it when was reading manuals.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing `Noto Sans CJK JP` & `Noto Serif CJK JP`.